# how to change the way showing plus before a non-leaf node into showing plus before a node containing any children in an extjs treepanel?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, treepanel

**Code:**
[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bXrGN/)

This is the modified tree data from an example of book `ExtJs in Action`:

```
     var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        root: {
            text: 'Root Node',
            expanded: false,
            children: [{
                text: 'Child 1',
                leaf: false     //<---------Modified (from true to false)
            }, {
                text: 'Child 2',
                leaf: true
            }, {
                text: 'Child 3',
                children: [{
                    text: 'Grand Child 1',
                    children: [{
                        text: 'Grand... you get the point',
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }
    });
```

When expanding `Root Node`, you would find a `+` before `Child 1` for this node is not a leaf. However, there is nothing in `Child 1`.

**Question:**

Is there some method to change the way of showing `+` before a node through judging whether there is any children node in it?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: How would you like it to behave?

By default, if leaf is not true, then the tree tries to load children from the server. A node that is leaf in fact but leaf is not true is something odd.

Comment: @Saki, There is no accesses to the server, it is only local. You can have a look at the Demo link above. I think it should be that there is no `+` before a node when the node has no any children. This way would be more intelligent. In fact, the ExtJs shows `+` before a non-leaf node not to judge whether there is any children.

Comment: If there are no children's to a given node then why do you want to show the + sign before that node ? just set the leaf property and the job is done.

Comment: @DeepakPatil, yes, what you said is one way to handle it. But, I wonder, is there other ways to change that showing `+` once the node are not a leaf.

Comment: @ShaoweiLing, Yes you can play around with css for those nodes, apply some extra css to the node.

Comment: If your project does not need this special behavior, it is not worth the effort, IMO.

Comment: @Saki, I am new to ExtJs and know little about the details, but i think it should be that I described above. So if we get it, the user experience would be better. @Ashish has a way to make it below. Surprised that just `loaded : true` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If parent has no children, then set **loaded** attribute as **true** in JSON responce or root(in your case).

your root config should look like this

```
root: {
        text: 'Root Node',
        expanded: false,
        children: [{
            text: 'Child 1',
            leaf: false,
            loaded:true
        }, {
            text: 'Child 2',
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: 'Child 3',
            children: [{
                text: 'Grand Child 1',
                children: [{
                    text: 'Grand... you get the point',
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
```

Comment: yes, it works. Thanks a lot. I wonder, is there some documents about the definition of tree store?